# Does this count towards read count?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

After querying out using CollectionsGroup, I tried to get parent's parent information like so:

```
db.collectionGroup('teams').where('players', 'array-contains', currentUser.uid).get().then(function(snapshots){
  snapshots.forEach((doc) => {
    doc.ref.parent.parent.get().then((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.data())
    })
  })
})
```

Does `doc.ref.parent.parent.get()` count against your total read count in Cloud Firestore?
I am thinking that it will, but I wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, any time you `get()` a document in the default way like this, while the app is online, you will be charged a read.  It does not matter what happened previously in the app.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Is it possible to do something like this without doing another `get()`? I'm just looking to optimize the call without having to increase read count.

Comment: If you want the contents of a document, you have to read it.  There aren't any workarounds for that.  That's the cost of the system.  There are no free reads.

Comment: thank you, I couldn't vote for your answer, but I marked it!